# how to make money payment?

Tags: payment, cash

I am using multibit and I need to buy some bitcoin (real money needed) and sell bitcoin(real money needed too)

But I cannot find any article on google that guide you how to make the money payment in transaction.

how can I pay or recieve money when I try to buy or sell bitcoin？

thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a Bitcoin exchange. The most popular one is [MtGox](https://www.mtgox.com/)

There are other ways but I think this is the safest one and easiest.

Comment: then what can I do with software wallet such as multibit?

Comment: They are only used to store your Bitcoins. You should always have a Bitcoin wallet where all your Bitcoin go and come from, this way it's a lot easier to track your money. But if you know what you are doing, you can directly send the money to your exchange address so you can save the transaction fee. I would recommand you to use a wallet client, instead of doing it online. That way its hard (in some ways) to get your Bitcoins stolen.

Comment: Is there any turtorial for that?

Comment: and when I "request bit coin" in multibit what would happen? how should I pay the seller

Comment: I dont want to be rude but if you are not able to use Google before asking a question, you shouldnt try to mine Bitcoins. Also, after some search I noticed that Multibit is in fact a wallet client (sorry for that). All you have to do to trade your Bitcoins is to go to mtgox.com, register an account and then give them the documents proving that you own your account and bank account. Once this is done, just send them your bitcoins by using the address they give you.

Comment: well, I thought multibit is a software for trading bitcoin...

Comment: I already got a mtgox account but I just feel it is not safe and I thought those wallet can allow you do the same thing on your own computer. anyway thx